# Universal installers on Linux

Tags: linux, deployment, repository, installation, packaging

I think its a fairly common problem, but I need to have community opinion and so I am posting this question.

**Use case:** I am trying to create a single package (32bit) for all the linux distros (32bit, 64bit) that I want to support.

**Problem: The INSTALLER**

- Needs to be able to run pre/post install scripts.
- Should be able to run on both 32bit and 64 bit machines
- Should be able to support older and newer distros (Centos 6 and above)
- Should have an online repository for updating packages.
- Should be able to run without X server
- Should not have any dependency on a software that cannot be installed using standard yum/zypper/apt commands. Should not depend on any non standard repository.

I came across this link:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4ohvur/nix_vs_snap_vs_flatpak_what_are_the_differences/
It lists many alternatives, but none of them seems to satisfy all the above requirements. (Or have I overlooked something)

In addition I looked at the following two alternatives:

1. QT installer Fwk (needs X to run, if I am right)
2. self-extracting scripts with tars bundled.

The only solution that fits all the needs is "self-extracting scripts with tars bundled". But it requires a lot of work, effectively managing all the installation/upgrade stuff myself. Before I go ahead with this alternative, can anyone please confirm if he/she has any success in creating a single package for many distros?

Comment: Please also specify the reason when you downvote the question. It does not make sense to downvote and have no opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe in the concept of rolling one's own installer with a self-extracting archive overly much. Every distro is different, and should be addressed using their own installation mechanisms. Also, writing your own installer is re-inventing the wheel.

I'd advertise using the packaging methods of all the distros you're targetting. Essentially, one SPEC file is typically enough to support CentOS 6,7, and all modern Fedora versions. Use `mock` or the copr service to generate all the binary packages for the distros you're targeting; then a debian rules file should be enough to generate Debian, Ubuntu and Mint packages. Add a pacman script if you want to support Arch Linux, too (it's pretty easy).

Admittedly, this way, you end up with a whole bunch of different packages, and not one. However, now you have an installer for each system that actually fits that system, is linked against the libraries available on that distro, and thus, you don't have to include all the dependencies like in a flatpack etc.

Installation from Distribution-specific packages is almost always "smoother" than installation through some self-extracting archive that wasn't actually designed for my specific distro version, so this is probably a big plus for your users. Also, having packages usually makes it very easy and stable to offer an update path, should you decide your software needs patches later on.

Comment: First of all, thanks Marcus, for giving an explaination, and not downvoting.. Also, I already have all my CMake files generating debs and RPMs for me, and thats how I am distributing my packages right now. That is no problem, but since the number of distros that we want to support is huge (count all legacy and new distros, 32 and 64 bit), the current problem is the number of packages to be distributed.

Comment: But: I don't see why reducing the number of packages really is actually a good thing. You see, we both agree one package per target distro is the best solution for the user; so although you might simply put all these packages into the same tar, you're not actually gaining any advantage.

Comment: So, even though I already have deb and rpm repositories setup, we dont want to use them any longer. the whole idea is to have just 1 set of binaries, and bundle them in an "Installer" somehow. This means that I would do away with the rpms and debs and just have "some installer" installing these binaries on users machines.

Comment: Why would you do that? Neither you nor your users win **anything** by getting such an installer. Just live with your N packages. How is having a couple of files a problem? Having proper repositiories has numerous advantages that your single installer doesn't have.

Comment: because this is somehow not interoperating with our current setup, for reasons which are beyond a technical explaination ;(

Comment: Well, at any rate, if you can't technically justify why having a single installer has anything but disadvantages, then I'd say you now have the reasons you should tell your management why not to do that.

Comment: Well, there are many advantages, that I feel have some weight, like creating a single package means we dont have to worry about creating a repo for all the distros, saving build effort, also helps  narrowing down debugging sessions from platform issues to code issues, having a package directly work on the newer distros, and probably, older distros also, not having to deal with the different (system repo provided) package names in our pre/post install scripts etc.. anyways, that is a seperate discussion, i suppose. Thanks a lot for a healthy discussion.

Comment: but you **won't** save build effort unless you make your installer include the dependencies instead of linking against distro-supplied libraries, which is far inferior than generating actual distro-targetting packages. I see your points – but I honestly think flatpacks and the like aren't a good thing – integration into a distro's environment is a benefit, not a downside :)